# 2 tables with some equil columns

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to select 2 tables with an inner join with some equal columns with 1 WHERE clause for the 2 tables?

Example:
Table user: fam_id, fam_status,
Table user_child: fam_id, fam_status

```
SELECT * from user INNER JOIN user_child ON user.fam_id=user_child.fam_id WHERE fam_id=14
```

Will this select the rows from Table user and Table user_child?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and results?

Comment: Nope - you should get a sql 1052 error fam_id is ambiguous.

Comment: I never tried but I don't think it will work. I think you need to use like this user.fam_id=14 && user_child.fam_id=14